# Unable to get the correct innerHTML after AJAX load

Tags: jquery

I was updating `innerHTML` of an element through `ajax` succesfully... But when i want to get same `innerHTML` of  that element using  `.htm()`, i could not get the updated innerHTML...

It returns the previous Mark up when the document was loaded.....

How to solve this..?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: First of all, please write the question subject clearly, try including some code of yours.

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but the jQuery method is `.html()`, **not** `.htm()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using html() try using inner html directly. i.e. instead of something like

```
var youobj = $(".someselector");
var html = yourobj.html();
```

do:

```
var youobj = $(".someselector");
var html = yourobj[0].innerHTML;
```

Although admittedly both should give the same result.

Comment: OOps i was doing wrong...i was trying to get innerHTML somewhere in the different js file before the ajax load....sorry guys,,,anyways thanks..!